# django model saving the data temporary

Tags: django, python-3.x, postgresql, django-models, django-views

I am using postgresql as database and it is just saving the data permanently into the database. So, given below is my views.py file

```
@login_required
def add_comment(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        comment = request.POST.get('comment')
        floor_id = request.POST.get('floor_id')
        question_id = request.POST.get('question_id')
        floor_detail = get_object_or_404(FloorDetail, id=floor_id)
        question = get_object_or_404(Question, id=question_id)
        answer, created = Answer.objects.get_or_create(floor_no=floor_detail, question=question)
        comment_obj = Comment.objects.create(answer=answer, comment=comment)
        print(answer, comment_obj)
        data = render(request,'mobile/include/single_comment.html', {'comment':comment_obj})

        if data:
            html=data
        else:
            html=None

        return HttpResponse(html)
    else:
        question_id = request.GET.get('question_id')
        floor_id = request.GET.get('floor_id')
        question = get_object_or_404(Question, id=question_id)
        floor_detail = get_object_or_404(FloorDetail, id=floor_id)
        answer = Answer.objects.filter(floor_no=floor_detail, question=question).first()
        comments = Comment.objects.filter(answer=answer)
        data = render(request,'mobile/include/comment.html', {'comments':comments})

        if data:
            html=data
        else:
            html=None

        return HttpResponse(html)
```

when i use print (answer, comment_obj) statement it is printing out both the objects on the terminal, however when check the database through django-admin interface the answer & comment_obj instance isn't shown, means data is not reflected there.
Please tell me how to fix it.

Comment: But you don't see the Answer and Comment models in admin or do you see those models but not the created records ?

Comment: not the records

Comment: please suggest something, how to solve it

Comment: I's possible that when you run the view i's takine the "else" instead of the if condition, did you check step by step that the code it's getting via if, i mean, that it is indeed receiving POST method ?

Comment: yes, i've checked that request is getting to POST  if block.

Comment: Awright, can you please post the print it shows about answer and comment_obj ?

Comment: Also your models.py please